LDR (unsigned offset) vs LDUR (unscaled)
If x1 contains 0x10001000, then I believe that these two instructions do the same thing, namely, they load four-bytes from 0x10001004-0x10001007 into w6.
  ldr   w6, [x1, #4]   // "Unsigned Offset" (immediate)
  ldur  w6, [x1, #4]   // "Unscaled" load


Link to the LDR instruction (scroll down to the "Unsigned Offset" variant).
Link to the LDUR instruction.

To summarize my understanding, the 32-bit LDR(immediate) is able to use POSITIVE multiples of 4 as the pre-increment.  The 64-bit LDR(immediate) is able to use positive multiples of 8 as the pre-increment.  It's clear that these next two instructions are illegal.
  ldr   w6, [x1, #1]   // ILLEGAL
  ldr   w6, [x1, #-4]  // ILLEGAL

If I want a negative offset, or if I want some unaligned transfer, then I must use ldur.
  ldur  w6, [x1, #1]        // Loads bytes from address 0x10001001-0x1001004
  ldur  w6, [x1, #-4]       // Loads bytes from address 0x10000ffc-0x1000fff

Question #1:
Why are there two different instructions? Why not just simplify and do this under the hood? I presume that an ldur may have much more latency than an ldr(immediate). Is ARM just trying to make it very visible that your code may be slower?
Edit: @PeterCordes reminded me that because the LDR instructions use positive multiples of four, they can support a much larger range of immediates.  I believe this is answered.
Question #2:
Obviously, SVE(vectors) would be better for this application, but I'm just using it to focus my understanding of ldur. On a recent Neoverse, which of these approaches is faster/better...?  (QEMU doesn't model what I need, so I cannot measure.)
      #1                        #2                  #3 (post-increment to destroy x1)
    ldur x2, [x1, # -4]       sub x1, x1, 4       ldr x2, [x1], #-4
    ldur x3, [x1, # -8]       ldr x2, [x1]        ldr x3, [x1], #-4
    ldur x4, [x1, #-12]       sub x1, x1, 4       ldr x4, [x1], #-4
    ldur x5, [x1, #-16]       ldr x3, [x1]        ldr x5, [x1], #-4
    ldur x6, [x1, #-20]       sub x1, x1, 4       ldr x6, [x1], #-4
    ldur x7, [x1, #-24]       ldr x4, [x1]        ldr x7, [x1], #-4
    ldur x8, [x1, #-28]       sub x1, x1, 4       ldr x8, [x1], #-4
    ldur x9, [x1, #-32]       ldr x5, [x1]        ldr x9, [x1], #-4
                              sub x1, x1, 4
                              ldr x6, [x1]
                              sub x1, x1, 4
                              ldr x7, [x1]
                              sub x1, x1, 4
                              ldr x8, [x1]
                              sub x1, x1, 4
                              ldr x9, [x1]

Edit: Here, I believe that @oldtimer has pointed me to ARM's "software optimization guide" which discusses the "recommended" way to do this sort of thing (which is effectively maximizing parallelism during loop unrolling).
Thanks!

Is ARM just trying to make it very visible that your code may be slower? - No, there are separate opcodes.  Scaling the immediate allows a larger range of offsets.  Using different mnemonics for the different opcodes makes the range limit difference more visible, instead of more complex rules for which offsets are allowed with ldr, with the assembler having to pick a valid encoding.

For performance, I'm pretty sure without looking at perf manuals that #1 will be at least as fast as the other options.  #3 probably has a serial dependency through x1 preventing multiple loads from running in parallel even if the CPU has multiple load ports.

It seems you're right about unsigned: https://godbolt.org/z/8bf75KfGW shows GCC and Clang only using ldr with an offset for return p[255] not p[-255].  For return p[-1], GCC prints the instruction as ldr     w0, [x0, -4], but clang shows it as ldur.  IDK if GCC is just expecting the assembler to handle it for you.

@PeterCordes The assembler actually puts in ldur if you use ldr with an odd displacement.  I think the separate ldur mnemonic is mainly useful so you can relocate the displacement.

Thanks @PeterCordes.  I actually got thinking about this question because I saw GCC(as) had replaced one of my ldr with an ldur.

I think there was a previous question about this, but I can't find it. It boils down to the simple fact that the machine has two options for encoding the immediate offset of a load instruction. It was a design principle of the assembly language that different encodings should be visible as different mnemonics, which is occasionally useful even though it also leads to oddities like this.

But I think this is a reasonable question and not opinion based. A "why" question like #1 can be answered by discussing the underlying principles and the pros and cons of the other options. And #2 is not opinion based at all, if you just rephrase "which would you expect to be faster?" to "which is faster?". I voted to reopen.

Arm publishes a Software Optimization Guide for each of their cores with full instruction timings.  Here is the one for Neoverse V1.  You can see that ldur has identical latency and throughput to ldr with immediate offset.

Even if ldur was slower, a better way than either of your #2 and #3 would be sub x1, x1, #32 / ldr w2, [x1, #28] / ldr w3, [x1, #24] / ... /  ldr w8, [x1, #4] / ldr w9, [x1].  That way after you take the one-cycle latency hit for the subtract, all the remaining load instructions are independent of each other and can execute as load pipelines become available. Arm recommends doing this kind of thing when unrolling loops, too.

First off, there is no answer here because this appears to be an architecture question, but the performance comes from the actual implementation.  ARM has a number/many of cores with these instructions and technically no two of those cores could perform the same.  Then you have the uncountable number of chip designs, and being a bus transaction that is outside ARMs control the primary performance driver comes from the chip folks not ARM nor the architecture.  Then throw in the reality that this product line is often used for operating system based systems with mmus, caches and slow dram.  For which performance tests on something like this are useless.  You need bare metal, internal, ideally fast, sram and 100% control over if anything is on (mmu, caches, etc) as they affect performance (yes 100% in the L1 cache can still affect performance).
If we break this down though from what you seem to be asking between the three test cases.  #2 appears to be you trying to make a point, perhaps serious perhaps not.  So #1 and #3 then talk about #2.
In both cases you have a register file read and an offset calculation.  We can get into not using a register file or having a multi ported sram and all that but let's think linear and single ported.  So ideally one clock will address the register file to get x1 and in that same clock the immedate based offset math.  We can then dream of the address going out on the read address bus the next cycle and the ack from the other side the cycle after that and the data coming back on the read address bus with the ack or the next clock.  Reality the data back from the read the zero extension is free within that cycle and the write to the register file assuming it is not busy.
The post increment and write to the register file happens in one clock, we already have x1 to perform the load so it is just a matter of doing the add which is free and the write at the end of that cycle.  Because the load in fantasy land takes at least two clock cycles then this should be free.
Even with a "Zero wait state" memory I expect 5 or more clocks on the processor (they still using AXI yes?) bus and maybe an extra one to get out of the pipe to that bus from the register file read/adjustment.
In this context so far neither #1 nor #3 has an advantage over each other from a clock performance perspective and should be equal.
I have seen (not arm) a possible optimization that is much more likely on #1 that on #3.  Load bus transactions generally fill the bus, let's assume 64 bit but even 128 would be better. Whether it is a byte, halfword, word, or double word (aligned) read then a whole bus width will come back (you do not expect to have a byte lane mask on a read), so
ldur x3, [x1, # -8]
ldur x3, [x1, # -12]

could technically be one bus transaction and not two.  Before I gave silicon a talking to I did confirm that when talking to memory address space had this optimization but when talking to a peripheral on the peripheral bus it was broken into separate transactions.  And here as well, likely through the mmu (Which is going to add one to many more clock cycles to EVERY transaction) to determine device from memory.  So I doubt arm would do this.  But it is technically possible.
I did not dive in as heavily as maybe I once would have, but the way things are today due to lazy programmers, x1 can likely be unaligned making either ldr or ldur perform an unaligned access.  Unaligned accesses on a bus like this turn into two separate transactions so double the number of processor bus clocks at a minimum.  Also reads are not fire and forget like writes you have to wait for the furthest end of the other side to respond and that value to come all the way back.  Even if you play bus games (cannot see arm doing that) to avoid two transactions the sram (cache, internal) may still have an extra clock/bus cycle at the sram due to the alignment.
The subtract one #2 is interesting, and technically can be the same performance if you think completely about the read cycles. The subtract with an immediate is going to be one clock to read the register file then the math and the write back are a second clock.  It is going to take a few clocks minimum to do the load, so depending on pipe design the subtract could be free...except...You are doubling the number of fetches...on the same bus...(it is not harvard no matter how many ways they try to say it, harvard is a text book thought process you cannot have a true harvard that is useful in an operating system or other similar environment.  Remember that modified harvard = modified von neumann and nobody says the latter they want to get the h word in there to trick you).  The fetches are going to interfere with the loads, so while it is the same number of loads it is twice as many fetches, the fetches are more optimized as they are multiple (like 4 or 8) instructions per so one overhead and 2 or 4 read data bus clocks, for the loads one overhead and one data bus clock per.  Assuming a 64 bit bus and you are able to saturate the read data bus (good luck with that) one fetch cycle for 4 instructions so one fetch to two loads.  3/2, 150%.
I do not think there was a real expectation for #2 to be equal though.
ARM defines architectures and then has one or more implementations, again no two have to be identical.  So even a logic sim with a perfect sram as fast as the processor bus can go I think #1 and #3 are the same performance and #2 is slower. The real world stuff that you can actually buy, there is no reason to expect that #1 by itself is going to perform the same on any two different platforms even if they bought the same core from arm.  And again if you throw in mmu, cache, dram and operating system, it is basically a waste of time even trying a test.
Because of how trivially easy it is the raspberry pi would be the primary starting point but unfortunately because it is dram based, the arm is a slave to the gpu and they both share and compete for the dram through a shared mmu based system.  Performance tests on the rpi, even bare metal, are not of interest.  I have done many 32 bit arm demonstrations but the last time I tried a 64 bit for an SO question, I was not able to beat the platform into submission and let me boot and own the processor bare metal against the internal sram.  And was not going to spend the money to buy many different platforms to find one I could beat up.  If I had one handy this would be a relatively quick test.
Bottom line though IMO, and this is an opinion based question since there is no single answer, the register file read of x1 is the same, the offset math is free, the bus cycles are the same, the post increment is free as is the zero extension so #1 and #3 should be identical if you can get a true apples to apples comparison test.  #2 the fetches are going to be measured and cause #2 to be some percentage slower, the fetches will dominate over the subtract, the subtract itself may end up being free and buried in the time waiting on a fetch or load.   The actual number of clock performance is determined by the chip vendor not arm, you are not processor bound here (unless you do an L1 cache thing but even there you are bound by the read of the sram and the fetches).

Thanks @old_timer. I do agree that this is a bit of an opinion question. I suppose PeterCordes answered the WHY part with "you can use bigger offset".  You have answered the second question. (Oh, and I am serious, not making a point.)

if that was your question, yes certainly if you have X immediate bits if you use bytes as a unit you can reach this far, halfwords twice as far and words four times as far, signed half as far.
